# Error when importing function that uses Turtle from a different file

Tags: python, python-turtle

I just started learning Python. I'm trying to use the turtle module. In the same directory, I have two files, script.py and test.py.

In script.py, I have a function written as follow:

```
import turtle


def circle(x, y, r, colour)
    turtle.showturtle()
    turtle.shape('classic')
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(x)
    turtle.sety(y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.pencolor(colour)
    turtle.fillcolor(colour)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(r)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.hideturtle()


circle(100, 100, 100, 'blue')

turtle.mainloop()
```

running script.py produces the blue circle.

I then want to import script.py to test.py. I did the following:

```
import script as file2

file2.circle(100, 100, 100, 'red')
```

*EDIT: I previously mistakenly written this as file2.script(), but it was noted correctly in python.

When I ran test.py without creating a configuration for script.py, without calling circle in script.py, I could draw the circle and edit its variable in test.py.

After i edit and save a configuration (simply using the directory for script.py and let it autofill), the function could not run and I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\project2\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    circle.draw_circle(100, 100, 100, 'red')
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\project2\script.py", line 5, in circle
    turtle.showturtle()
  File "<string>", line 5, in showturtle
turtle.Terminator

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I can't seem to revert what happened. What have I done wrong, and how can I import the circle function from script.py to test.py? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to import the circle function from `script.py` tp `test.py` you could make the following changes in your code:

In script.py:

```py
import turtle


def circle(x, y, r, colour):
    turtle.showturtle()
    turtle.shape('classic')
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(x)
    turtle.sety(y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.pencolor(colour)
    turtle.fillcolor(colour)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(r)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.mainloop()
```

In `test.py`:

```py
import script as file2

file2.circle(100, 100, 100, 'red')
```

By doing this your code runs only when the function is called.

Comment: Thank you for responding! The way you proposed woked! However, I run into problems once again when I try to put it in a larger function. I will post the problem below, if you have the time to look at it I'd really appreciate it

Comment: You can thank me by accepting or upvoting the answer :)

Comment: Btw you can post your problem here or just edit the question

Comment: This doesn't work properly.  Add a second circle call, e.g. `file2.circle(50, 50, 50, 'blue')` and you won't see the second circle as the first call turns over control to tkinter's event loop and doesn't return until the turtle environment is pulled down.

Comment: Just remove the `turtle.mainloop()` from the Script.py file. This will draw the blue circle over the red one

Comment: Thanks, I just gained enough forum points to be able to upvote. I figured out my other problem, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with an arrangement like:

script.py

```
import turtle

def circle(x, y, radius, colour):
    turtle.showturtle()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color(colour)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(radius)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.hideturtle()
```

test.py

```
import turtle
import script as file2

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('classic')

file2.circle(100, 100, 100, 'red')
file2.circle(50, 50, 50, 'blue')

turtle.mainloop()
```

This should allow you to call the `circle` function in script.py multiple times.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding! As a follow-up question, is import turtle necessary in test.py? would it not already be imported along with script.py?

Comment: @AppleJuice, you can try it and see.  I would leave the import personally as test.py references turtle methods and has (should have) no idea if/how script.py imports turtle.